# Do Dawn Redwood trees leaf-out in early, mid, or late spring?

Tags: trees, leaves, conifers, redwood

[image]

<sup>*[Image Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Metasequoia%20glyptostroboides%22%20bud&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjhwZCOy_z5AhWhrnIEHcioDKIQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22Metasequoia%20glyptostroboides%22%20bud&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoFCAAQgAQ6BAgAEB46BggAEB4QCFCHEFicE2DaFGgAcAB4AIAB0wGIAcIDkgEFMy4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=cFwVY-HJIKHdytMPyNGykAo&bih=969&biw=1920&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA931CA931#imgrc=7AVXz5vfb6BOtM)*</sup>

I'm looking for trees that come to life in early spring.

For example, some plants that are aesthetically pleasing in early spring are:

- Prunus
- Cornelian cherry
- Japanese quince
- Haskap
- Alpine strawberries
- Ribes
- Rhubarb

*(all have either early leaves or early flowers)*

---

**Question:**

Compared to other landscape plants, does [dawn redwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasequoia_glyptostroboides) (Metasequoia glyptostroboides) leaf-out in: A) early spring, B) mid-spring, or C) late spring?

For what it's worth, I'm located east of Toronto/Zone 6.